# Get the attributed name of a callback function in python

Tags: python, function, class, callback, rename

I'm trying to manage some functions in python by setting class members attributes and here's the problem

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.callback=b

    def a(self,name):
        print(name)

def b():                # a function that does anything
    print("I am d")

t=Test()
t.a(t.callback.__name__)   #Prints 'b'
```

So I get 'b' printed but I wish it could be 'callback' instead, so I can use this name in 'a' function to find other members in my object with a name that begin with 'callback'

Is there a way to get this?
Thank's in advance

Comment: No, you can't (really should not) go from a function's `__name__` to its variable name, or from any value to any name. We recently had a related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53280530/why-does-an-imported-function-as-another-name-keep-its-original-name). `self.callback = b` is just an assignment of one more name (of which there could be thousands) to some function object in memory. In any, case, when you can write `t.callback` you know `t` has an attribute named `callback` already.

Comment: There is in principle a way,but it would be horrendously slow. Not to mention rather confusing for maintenance. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Ok I see, thank's for the link. So if I understand well, it's not possible to get the other name because self.callback = b does not replicate the function so it use assignment name

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I use a few callback functions in a object assigned this way and each of them have a related variable also in this object. And I have a last function that call one of the callback and must also use the related data. So as the callback functions and data have similar name, I thought it would be easy to do it without passing the data in parameter

Comment: @MisterMiyagi but this was on purpose to optimize computing time so I maybe go to try other options

Comment: You might be looking for a simple dict. Functions are valid dict keys.